# Android - Using Filechannel to copy file at sd card isn't possible?

Tags: android, android-sdcard, android-external-storage, filechannel

I made this method to copy file from inputpath to outputpath. It works when input is located in sdcard, and output is located in local storage, But when I change output to a file located in sdcard, it doesn't work and doesn't show any error. How can I fix this???

- I checked output with file.canwrite() and it returned false.. Why??

  ```
  public void copyFile(String inputPath, String outputPath) {
  FileInputStream fis = null;
  FileOutputStream fos = null;
  FileChannel in = null;
  FileChannel out = null;
  try{
      fis = new FileInputStream(inputPath);
      fos = new FileOutputStream(outputPath);
      in = fis.getChannel();
      out = fos.getChannel();
      in.transferTo(0, in.size(), out);
  } catch(Exception e){
      e.printStackTrace();
  }
  finally {
      try{
          if(out != null) out.close();
          if(in != null) in.close();
          if(fis != null) fis.close();
          if(fos != null) fos.close();
      }
      catch (Exception e) {
          e.printStackTrace();
      }
  }
  ```

  }

Answer (score 0):

Try to add ***fos.flush()*** after re row *"in.transferTo(0, in.size(), out);"*

Comment: @YooMinjun did you find a solution? If yes, what was the problem?

Comment: It wasn't possible to write on sdcard directly. So I used DocumentFile. @MihaiBC

Comment: @YooMinjun Write it as an answer and mark this solved please.